# How to invert crop selection?

Tags: gimp

[Invert selection](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-selection-invert.html) feature doesn't apply to the [crop](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-crop.html) tool.

Inverting crop selection would be useful in removing black bars from letterboxed images, for instance:

[image: letterboxed image]

Comment: (autocrop and zealous crop don't entirely remove unwanted area from this image)

Comment: Because they remove uniform colors and the black margins are far from uniform. Start `Windows>Dockable dialogs>Histogram` and make a selection on the full width of a margin, you will see a [rather wide range of black values](http://i.imgur.com/LmgRRQn.png).

Comment: @xenoid: Yes, I noticed that when zooming in. Perhaps YouTube's compression (image source) causes this.

Comment: I've now removed the demonstration image as I feel that it doesn't in any way improve the question.

Comment: But the question without image is useless... Anyway if what you want to do is keep the image at the center, then you select it wit the crop tool and don't need to invert the selection. You can also use a rectangle select and `Image>Crop to selection` (again, no need to invert anything). In both cases, the crop keeps the selection and sheds what wasn't selected.

Comment: The image is in my answer anyhow lol

Comment: This is a classic example of "Describe the goal, not the step" when asking questions: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to just use the Rectangle Select Tool...

- Click-drag around what you want to keep
- Go to Image > Crop to Selection

[image: Gimp Menu]

And done. Save it out...

[image]

Comment: Your answer applies to this specific image, but doesn't answer the question. I've only used the image as an example, "How to invert crop selection?" is the question. Perhaps I shouldn't have added the image in the first place.

Comment: I've now removed the image.

Comment: No I'm pretty sure my answer applies to any image at all. Make a selection and crop. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaking the Crop tool for a selection tool. It isn't. There is a Rectangle selection tool for this, and the selection it creates can be inverted.

Now, on your image:

- If you want to restrict the image to its center and remove the dark margins, then you use the Crop tool, and there is no need to invert the selection.
- If you want to delete the dark margins without changing the size of the layer image, then you use a Rectangle selection on the part you want to keep, then `Select>Invert` and `Edit>Clear`.
- If you want to keep the dark margins, then you use a Rectangle selection on the part you want to delete, then `Edit>Clear`.